# New .htaccess puzzle

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this link:
index.php/forums/viewforum/5/

Now, I want that "forums" word in URL to become dynamic such that which ever word I replace it with, it still redirects to the same URL.

For example, if I have:
ProductA/viewforum/5/
it redirects to:
forums/viewforum/5/

For example, if I have:
ProductB/viewforum/13/
it redirects to:
forums/viewforum/13/

In other words, if there's a "view forum" word in the URL, it should trigger this rewrite.

I already have a .htaccess that removes the index.php from the URL so the rewrite rule should consider that too.

Is it possible?

HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (member)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/404 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^[.*]+/(viewforum/[0-9]+/?)$ /forums/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/ddco/public_html/index.php/$1? [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /forums/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(viewforum/[0-9]+/?)$ /forums/$1 [L,NC]
```

Also suggesting you to post your current .htaccess rules as well for further investigation.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the "forum" completely from the URL? I mean, if the actual URL is accessed, which has "forum" in the URL, I need to remove that word "forum" from the URL.

Comment: That was not part of your original question. If somebody enters `/index.php/forums/viewforum/5/` what it should become?

Comment: It should not let access forums. If forums keyword is used in URL, just show 404 error!

Comment: It's not working..here's full htaccess file:  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (member)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/404 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(viewforum/[0-9]+/?)$ /forums/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/domaina/public_html/index.php/$1? [L]  
</IfModule>

Comment: Very difficult to read it in comments, can you edit the question and update it here (or create a new question with this new problem).

Comment: I suggest creating a new question with the link to this one. I will try my best to answer from fresh.

Comment: Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323169/htaccess-puzzle-help-needed