# .htaccess puzzle, help needed

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this link:
index.php/forums/viewforum/5/

Now, I want that "forums" word in URL to become dynamic such that which ever word I replace it with, it still redirects to the same URL.

For example, if I have:
ProductA/viewforum/5/
it redirects to:
forums/viewforum/5/

For example, if I have:
ProductB/viewforum/13/
it redirects to:
forums/viewforum/13/

In other words, if there's a "view forum" word in the URL, it should trigger this rewrite.

I already have a .htaccess that removes the index.php from the URL so the rewrite rule should consider that too.

Is it possible?

HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule member http://%{HTTP_HOST}/404 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(viewforum/[0-9]+/?)$ /forums/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond $1 !^(images|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1? [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd and 3rd rules look suspect.

Have your full code like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule member http://%{HTTP_HOST}/404 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(viewforum/[0-9]+/?)$ /forums/$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This didn't work. When I try URL http://domain.com/ABC/viewforum/1 it should ideally call http://domain.com/forums/viewforum/1 while keeping the http://domain.com/ABC/viewforum/1 in the address bar. But it shows a 404 page.

Comment: Guess we are close..now it gives 500 internal server error for URLs that have "viewforum" in it, so http://domain.com/ABC/viewforum/1 and http://domain.com/forums/viewforum/1 both gives 500 error. All other URLs work fine.

Comment: Now it's the 404 error for "ABC/viewforum/2" and "forums/viewforum/2" works fine. I guess the problem is somewhere in "RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(viewforum/[0-9]+/?)$ /forums/$1 [L,NC]" where you replace only viewforum/2 with forums/viewforum/2...so eventually URL becomes domain.com/ABC/forums/viewforum/2 which actually is 404. The URL domain.com/ABC/viewforum/2 should call domain.com/forums/viewforum/2 ---is it that way?

Comment: No since replacement starts with `/forums` it cannot become `/ABC/forums/...`

Comment: When you get 404 what is the full error you get? Can you check Apache error.log for this 404 also?

Comment: /home/ddco/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteRule: invalid HTTP response code for flag 'R'

Comment: That error is due to some other code you have. You should post your complete .htaccess and also this error is not the cause of 404 that is some other line

Comment: I have pasted the exact htaccess I have on server. Actually it's not 404. What happens is when I try domain.com/ABC/viewforum/2 it just opens the home page of the site..so I assumed it is 404 and thats why it opens the home page. When I try domain.com/forums/viewforum/2 it opens the proper forum page.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `/forums/` folder also by any chance? Also try updated code

Comment: Now I get the 404 message in browser for both "forums" and "abc" in URL : The requested URL /forums/viewforum/1 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: In error logs: File does not exist: /home/ddco/public_html/forums and File does not exist: /home/ddco/public_html/404.shtml

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside /forums/ folder also by any chance?

Comment: No..it's not there..actually forum is a module of the CMS (Expressionengine) that I am using.

Comment: Ah that explains. You never told this before. That CMS may not work with internally rewritten URIs. Put R in `[L,NC,R]` in the viewforum rule to see if that works.

Comment: It didn't work. But it should be doable with this CMS (EE), because this other site does the same thing - http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/jb-friendly/viewforum/1548 if you notice the "forums" is replaced with "jb-friendly" and it works fine.

Comment: Or ....is it possible to just remove the "forums" word completely from the URL and not put another word instead of it..what we were trying? I mean I am fine with this also - domain.com/viewforum/1 I just don't want a listing of ALL forums if someone access the URL domain.com/forums

Comment: See updated rule and then try opening: `http://domain.com/ABC/viewforum/2` Make sure URL is exactly this (just replace domain.com nothing else) If this doesn't work then I suspect there is something in your local setup that I am unaware of.

Comment: This opens the forum now..but changes ABC to "forums". It doesn't retain ABC in URL..so seems it's redirecting? I need to retain the "ABC" in the URL..and if someone tries to access domain.com/forums ..then show a 404 page. But I guess we are close :)

Comment: Yes it is, I just want to show you that rule is correct. Just removing `R` may not work due to your CMS framework.

Comment: so you mean it cannot be done? but it is happening on devot-ee.com which uses the same cms.